# Bash script to download latest release from GitHub

Tags: bash, github, curl, github-api, xidel

Looking for a simple way to download a .zip from a latest GitHub release.
There are other similar questions, but I havent been able to get them to work. :(

Trying to pull latest release from https://github.com/CTCaer/hekate

Currently ive got:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/CTCaer/hekate/releases/latest | jq -r ".assets[] | select(.name | test(\"hekate_ctcaer\")) | .browser_download_url"
```

trying to fetch the url of the latest .zip and only grab the "hekate_ctcaer_X.X.X_Nyx_X.X.X.zip"

I saw someone trying to achieve this with 'Xidel', so im open to trying that if someone knows the syntax to grab a specific file from the GitHub api.

As I understand it (?), the Github API spits out an array for the release 'assets', so im trying to specify an item in this array that matches "hekate_ctcaer", and download the specified file.

Comment: I understood your question to mean that you only want the URL of the zip file. Let me know if you were also looking to download the zip in one line.

Comment: Thanks! Also looking to download the zip

Comment: Okay, updated the answer to also download the zip

Comment: Do you mean: `url=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/CTCaer/hekate/releases/latest | jq -r ".assets[] | select(.name | test(\"hekate_ctcaer\")) | .browser_download_url"); wget "$url"`?

Comment: @dan hm maybe...?

Answer (score 1):

This will print out the url to the zip file of the latest release:

```
curl -sL https://api.github.com/repos/CTCaer/hekate/tags \
  | jq -r '.[0].zipball_url' \
  | xargs -I {} curl -sL {} -o latest.zip
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and see if it works, would there be anything I should watch for implementing this across different OS's?

Comment: also how would I modify this for the following:

https://github.com/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases/tag/1.3.2

the .zip AND the .bin

Comment: Also is there a neat way to rename the downloaded file within the same command, or just do it as a separate command after?

Comment: different OS's - no, i don't thinks so (i tried this on Mac and Debian and it worked).
"-o latest.zip" - this part names the file, so change it to whatever you need.
please accept the answer and ask your 2nd comment in a new question and i'll help you there.

Answer (score 1):

Github is also a compatible git repo. I provide a new train of thought.

- use `git ls-remote` to fetch last release tag.

```
git -c 'versionsort.suffix=-' ls-remote --tags --sort='v:refname' http://github.com/CTCaer/hekate.git
| tail --lines=1
| cut --delimiter='/' --fields=3
```

Here this examples outputs `v5.8.0`

- then clone remote repo

```
git clone --branch v5.8.0 http://github.com/CTCaer/hekate.git
```

- zip repos to zipped file.

```
zip hekate.zip -r hekate/
```

Comment: this may work, but I'd like to avoid git, as its less likely that majority of users would have git installed, whereas curl is more ubiquitous and jq seems quite a light download that I can include.

This is also to go in almost an automation script, so it seems the other solution is more concise

Answer (score 1):

> *I saw someone trying to achieve this with 'Xidel'*

I assume you're referring to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69298758/2703456). That answer is tagged [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), so you first of all have to swop the quotes for [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (`"function('string')"` --> `'function("string")')`. And secondly, you're right. You have to select the appropriate object in the "assets"-array.

```
$ xidel -s "https://api.github.com/repos/CTCaer/hekate/releases/latest" \
  -f '$json/(assets)()[starts-with(name,"hekate_ctcaer")]/browser_download_url' \
  --download '{substring-after($headers[starts-with(.,"Content-Disposition")],"filename=")}'
```

This downloads *'hekate_ctcaer_5.8.0_Nyx_1.3.0.zip'* in the current dir.
With [r8389 or newer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/) you can just use `--download .`.

> *also how would I modify this for the following: [github.com/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases/tag/1.3.2](https://github.com/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases/tag/1.3.2) the .zip AND the .bin*

Strictly speaking you'd have to raise a new question for this, but ok.

It appears that (at the moment) v1.3.2 is also the latest release for this repo, so you can use...

```
$ xidel -s "https://api.github.com/repos/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases/latest" \
  -e '$json'
```

or alternatively...

```
$ xidel -s "https://api.github.com/repos/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases" \
  -e '$json()[tag_name="1.3.2"]'
```

The "assets"-array here has just 2 objects; one with the zip-file and one with the bin-file, so just "follow" (`--follow` / `-f`) the 2 "browser_download_url"-keys to download:

```
$ xidel -s "https://api.github.com/repos/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases" \
  -f '$json()[tag_name="1.3.2"]//browser_download_url' \
  --download .
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump this topic, but here's my take on downloading file `$file` from the latest release of `$repo` by `$owner`

compatible with git-bash on windows (doesn't have `rev`...)

```bash
echo "fetching latest version"
latest_version=`
    curl https://github.com/$owner/$repo/releases/latest --verbose 2>&1 |
    grep Location |
    sed -e "s|.*/v||"`

echo "version: $latest_version"

# if the version number is in the file name, append it
# example:
# file=somefile-$latest_version.ext

link="https://github.com/$owner/$repo/releases/download/v$latest_version/$file"

echo "$link"

curl -o "destination/folder/$file" -L "$link"
```